# how do you pass the value/string of textbox to a XtraLabel in XtraReport in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to pass a value or string from a textbox to the XtraLabel, what i did so far is create a parameter then send the value directly into the parameter then `Data Bind` the labels with my created parameters.

my code is this:

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraPrinting
Imports DevExpress.XtraReports.UI

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim reports As New XtraReport1()
        Dim pt As New ReportPrintTool(reports)

        reports.GetValue.Value = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
        pt.AutoShowParametersPanel = True
        pt.ShowPreviewDialog()

    End Sub
End Class
```

it does pass the value however i have to click submit from parameters panel to pass the value or string to my `GetValue` Parameter which isn't what i want, and when i set `pt.AutoShowParametersPanel = False` it doesn't create any document at all. I want to enter a value from the textbox and when i click the button it will automatically load the value from textbox to the xtralabel in XtraReport1. Please help and also, is there another way to do this properly? as much as possible i want to use parameters but any kind of method will do. thank you.

Form1 picture:

[image]

XtraReport1 picture:

[image]

edit: i forgot to mention that this is a test program

Comment: i think your want the parameter which is not visible in the parameters panel, so set the parameter.Visible=false in the property grid. if you want not to wait the parametrs submission at all, execute the code "reports.RequestParameters = False". passing the parameter values should works fine using your code. you can share your project here. compress it and share using onedrive/dropbox/googledrive/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i read the devexpress website again to see how to use parameters, i almost failed to notice the "Tip" from the Web. What you need to do is:

```
reports.Parameters("GetValue").Value = TextBox1.Text
reports.RequestParameters = False
```

in that way the report won't ask for input and it will automatically send and submit input to the parameter/s

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim parameter As New Parameter() With {.Name = "GetValue", .Type = GetType(String), .Value = TextBox1.Text}
reports.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```

[Create a Report Parameter](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/9997/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-report-parameters/create-a-report-parameter)